# Как увеличить в размере boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: Как мне]

Как мне сделать чтобы эти надписи не слипались можно ли как-то  в размере увеличить? В датасете просто много колонок. И вот 2 этих значения на боксплоте где только минимальное значение и аномалии показаны это как понять

Comment: код свой в вопросе приведите, если хотите конкретного ответа. код должен быть в текстовом виде.

Comment: что касается двух боксов на графике, которые слились в одну линию - нужно смотреть исходные данные. либо там мало значимых данных, либо у них действительно такое странное распределение.

Comment: @strawdog Да наверное там и то и другое судя по точкам этим сверху - и мало данных и распределены в ноль и вверх туда отдельными выбросами, вообще без промежуточных значений.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете не только увеличить размер холста, но и управлять метками по осям. например, развернуть их на 90 градусов:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
df["deck"] = df["deck"].apply(lambda x: x*15)

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, y="fare", x="deck", hue="deck", dodge=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А, да, я недочитал вопрос, тут скорее про метки и правда.

Answer (score 0):

`Seaborn` по большому счёту это надстройка над `maptlotlib`. Поэтому довольно много что можно делать через `matplotlib`. Можете создать новую фигуру или `subplots` или ещё что в этом роде и это подействует на отрисовку через `Seaborn`. Вот через фигуру пример:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.boxplot(data=list(range(100)))
```